Blender 4.1 how to disable environmental lighting in the shading viewport
I am using Blender 4.1 and in the Shading Viewport I find it hard to see because of the environmental texture. How can I disable it or set it to white? This only happens in Material Preview mode. It looks find in Render Preview


If you want to deactivate the Material environment effect, open the Viewport Shading panel and enable the World option, now it's the World settings that will be reflected and that will light the object:

